# correct htaccess query string code

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, prestashop-1.6

Is this the correct code for my HTACCESS to setting up header to noindex nofollow

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)cart? [NC]

 RewriteRule .* - [E=MY_SET_HEADER:1]

 Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" env=MY_SET_HEADER
```

so that the following URL cannot be indexed by search engines.

http://www.mysite.com/cart?qty=1&id_product=8&token=7775324f4cd8c884155af53ca90e44ad&add

Actually moz analytics crawling these types of URL which is in 
`<a href="http://www.mysite.com/cart?qty=1&id_product=8&token=7775324f4cd8c884155af53ca90e44ad&add">Add To Cart</a>`

as a duplicate page content. Dont know why as these URL are just a Add to cart URL and these are nothing to do with any content.

Also I need suggestion for any online tutorial on playing with htaccess .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`/cart` isn't QUERY_STRING but Request URI. You can use this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^cart/?$ - [E=MY_SET_HEADER:1]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava..I am a great Fan of you but couldn't get connected. I tried to connect with you via your website and linked in but cant..:(

And thanks for the reply. I am sure your solution will work. Any suggestion on how to mastering on HTACCESS please?

Comment: I make sure to respond to each & every connection message on LinkedIn and and my blog. Please let me know your LinkedIn id and I will send a request to you to connect immediately. For mod_rewrite I find http://askapache.com pretty good resource.

Comment: WOW..Thank you soo much...my linked in ID is (http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=200717928) and I also I just followed you on twitter :-)

Comment: I Sent request as colleague :-)